# Why use class only protocols in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, protocols

Can anyone please explain class only protocols to me in Swift. I understand what protocols are and why we use them. I also understand that its recommended to use class only protocols when we use reference type objects in it and want to limit the protocol conformation to classes only. However, I can't find any good answer to support that recommendation. Why is it recommended? What is the drawbacks of using normal protocols in that case.

Comment: *Use a class-only protocol when the behavior defined by that protocol’s requirements assumes or requires that a conforming type has reference semantics rather than value semantics.*  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_422

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One use case:

- You have a "delegate" protocol and someone wants to have a `weak` property of that protocol type. `weak` can only be used on reference types; therefore, the protocol must be class-only.

Answer (score 0):

Another use case *used to be* to extend reference types to adopt protocols. You can't extend `AnyObject` itself (to inherit from another protocol, or for any other reason) but you have any reference types you want adopt a protocol inherited from `AnyObject`.

For example, having class equality based on unique identity is often a perfectly fine solution, so you could adopt `EquatableObject`:

```swift
public protocol EquatableObject: AnyObject, Equatable { }

public extension EquatableObject {
  static func == (class0: Self, class1: Self) -> Bool {
    class0 === class1
  }
}
```

But now, we have protocol extension constraints (using where clauses), so instead of extending `AnyObject`, we can extend the protocol, and use `AnyObject` as a constraint. It looks backwards but operates identically, and removes the need for our own protocol.

```swift
public extension Equatable where Self: AnyObject {
  static func == (class0: Self, class1: Self) -> Bool {
    class0 === class1
  }
}
```

Comment: why you need where Self:AnyObject for Equatable in this case ? just Equatable is not enough ?

Comment: No. `===` is not defined for value types.

Comment: could you share same version of extension for value types then or link please ?

Comment: Read this page; it's automatically synthesized. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable