# When to use `protocol` and `protocol: class` in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have setup a protocol to send some information back to the previous VC.

I define it like this:

```
protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate: class  {
    func didSearch(Parameters:[String: String]?)
}
```

But what is the difference when using:

```
protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate  {
        func didSearch(Parameters:[String: String]?)
    }
```

And when should I use a `: class` protocol?

Comment: Depends whether everything that conforms to `FilterViewControllerDelegate` is a `class`, and you want to treat things typed as `FilterViewControllerDelegate` as having reference semantics (which, for example, will allow you to use the `weak` attribute, which I suspect you may need). See for example: [swift protocol 'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471858/swift-protocol-weak-cannot-be-applied-to-non-class-type).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554034/why-use-class-only-protocols-in-swift

Answer (score 68, accepted):

### Swift 4 version

`AnyObject` added to a protocol definition like this

```
protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject  {
    func didSearch(parameters:[String: String]?)
}
```

means that only a class will be able to conform to that protocol.

So given this

```
protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject  {
    func didSearch(parameters:[String: String]?)
}
```

You will be able to write this

```
class Foo: FilterViewControllerDelegate {
    func didSearch(parameters:[String: String]?) { }
}
```

but **NOT** this

```
struct Foo: FilterViewControllerDelegate {
    func didSearch(parameters:[String: String]?) { }
}
```

---

### Swift 3 version

`:class` added to a protocol definition like this

```
protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate: class  {
    func didSearch(Parameters:[String: String]?)
}
```

means that only a class will be able to conform to that protocol.

So given this

```
protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate: class  {
    func didSearch(Parameters:[String: String]?)
}
```

You will be able to write this

```
class Foo: FilterViewControllerDelegate {
    func didSearch(Parameters:[String: String]?) { }
}
```

but **NOT** this

```
struct Foo: FilterViewControllerDelegate {
    func didSearch(Parameters:[String: String]?) { }
}
```

Comment: Swift 4 doc says to use `AnyObject` instead of `class` after protocol declaration. What's the difference?

Comment: as @nekonari said, regarding to Swift 4 syntax you should use AnyObject. Please look through this excellent video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5c3MDbgn-c&t=966s

Comment: @LucaAngeletti If we don't use "AnyObject" does it implies that all the three Class, Struct and enum can conform to that protocol ?

Answer (score 29):

There's also another thing about marking protocols with the `class`/`AnyObject` keyword.

Given a protocol like this:

### Swift 4 and above (according to [docs](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OptimizationTips.rst#advice-mark-protocols-that-are-only-satisfied-by-classes-as-class-protocols)):

```
protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject  {
    func didSearch(with parameters: [String: String]?)
}
```

### Pre-Swift 4 syntax:

```
protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate: class  {
    func didSearch(with parameters: [String: String]?)
}
```

For example, let's assume that you're creating a DetailViewController with delegate property of `FilterViewControllerDelegate` type:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: FilterViewControllerDelegate
}
```

If you didn't mark that protocol with `class` keyword, you wouldn't be able to mark that `delegate` property as a `weak` one.

Why?

It's simple - only class based properties can have weak relationships.
If you're trying to avoid a reference cycle, that's the way to go

Comment: This the best answer I have read so far. Everyone is saying its meaning but no one says why it should be used. Thank you!

Comment: Great summary.  That helps more than anything else I've read on the topic.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the benefit to weakify a delegate property? I mean, any condition in real life where a memory leak can occur if we do not weakify the delegate property?

Answer (score 11):

## Swift 5.1, Xcode 11 syntax:

```
protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
       func didSearch(Parameters:[String: String]?)
}
```

this protocol can be adopted by only classes.

**To answer your first question** -

> But what is the difference when using:

the difference from this:

```
protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate  {
        func didSearch(Parameters:[String: String]?)
}
```

is that this protocol can adopt value types, such enums and structs as well.

**To answer your second question** -

> And when should I use a : class protocal?

when you should use class protocol I would like to describe next example from delegate pattern:
Imagine that you have delegate protocol.

```
protocol PopupDelegate: AnyObject {
    func popupValueSelected(value: String)
}
```

and in another class you want to create a property

```
var delegate: PopupDelegate?
```

But this has strong reference that could bring you to problems with memory leaks. One way to fix memory leak is to make delegate property - weak. Until we will not make our protocol only available to apply for classes, Swift thinks we could apply our protocol also to value types.

```
weak var delegate: PopupDelegate?
```

If you try to declare your delegate like weak you will see next error:

> 'weak' var only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types,
>   not 'PopupDelegate'

But we cant apply weak to value types. So we need to restrict our protocol to a reference type, so swift knows that its a reference type.
To make you available to declare this delegate as weak you need to restrict your protocol to be used by classes only:

```
protocol PopupDelegate: AnyObject {
    func popupValueSelected(value: String)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It means that the protocol you define can be adopted only by classes, not structures or enums.

From [Official Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html):

```
protocol SomeClassOnlyProtocol: class, SomeInheritedProtocol {
    // class-only protocol definition goes here }
```

> In the example above, SomeClassOnlyProtocol can only be adopted by class types. It is
>   a compile-time error to write a structure or enumeration definition
>   that tries to adopt SomeClassOnlyProtocol.

Comment: I found this code where the use a class protocal:
``protocol MenuViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func menuViewControllerDidTouchTop(controller: MenuViewController)
}``
But whats the purpose of sending the VC as a parameter in the protocal function?

Comment: It's purpose is that you can fetch some useful data from that parameter. For example you can set some variables in a controller and then notify your delegate about and event (for example Save action from user). Passing vc to it's delegate makes it possible to fetch any public data from the caller.

Comment: it doesnt fetch any data. All it does in VC1 is this:
``func menuViewControllerDidTouchTop() {
        animateMenuButton()
    }``
It runs a function that fires an animation. So I dont get why it would need any data

Comment: Sometimes delegate doesn't need to know anything except that the event occurred, but there are some cases when it really needs to use some of  the caller's data as I said. So it's a good practice to define a protocol, which will satisfy those needs and then delegate can ignore it or use it.

Comment: The main idea is that there may be multiple object implementing the protocol your define. Some of them may ignore the parameter you pass and some of them may use it.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.2 Update:

To declare class only protocol now write:

```
protocol SomeClassOnlyProtocol: AnyObject, SomeInheritedProtocol {
    // class-only protocol definition goes here
}
```

instead of

```
protocol SomeClassOnlyProtocol: class, SomeInheritedProtocol {
    // class-only protocol definition goes here
}
```

The second snippet still seems to work for now. 
Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html