# Why do Swift Class-Only Protocols need AnyObject Inheritance?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out Swift Documentation:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html

But I stuck at this issue, Why need AnyObject, I mean why i need to use that kind of restriction ?
Is that a bad idea to not restrict for value and reference types just not using Any or AnyObject ?

```
protocol SomeClassOnlyProtocol: AnyObject, SomeInheritedProtocol {
    // class-only protocol definition goes here
}
```

Anyone can explain me some example with codes especially will be very helpful. Thanks.

By the way that answer can be good but literally explanations made me confusing
[Why use class only protocols in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554034/why-use-class-only-protocols-in-swift)

Comment: The main use case is the lone answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554034/why-use-class-only-protocols-in-swift: you want to have a `weak` variable whose type is a protocol (most often in the form of a delegate). Structs can't be `weak`, only objects — so to ensure that the values of your variable can only be objects, you need to restrict the protocol to be class-bound with `AnyObject`.

Comment: thanks for answer i edited my question, could you explain with written codes ? @ItaiFerber

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you write a protocol, you define an interface for the types which adopt, or *conform* to the protocol:

```swift
// Every Greeter has a greeting message
// and a way for it to present that message.
protocol Greeter {
    var greeting: String { get }
    func greet()
}

extension Greeter {
    // Default implementation for the `greet` method.
    func greet() {
        print(self.greeting)
    }
}
```

This gives consistent behavior to every type which conforms and lets you treat them all in the same way regardless of what they are. For instance, a type can store a value bound to a protocol type:

```swift
struct Store {
    // The name of the store.
    var name: String

    // The address of the store.
    var address: String

    // An entity that greets customers when they walk in.
    var greeter: Greeter
}
```

In this case, `Store.greeter` can be set to any value or object which conforms to the `Greeter` protocol:

```
struct Bell: Greeter {
    let greeting = "Ding!"
}

class Person: Greeter {
    let greeting: String

    init(name: String) {
       greeting = "Welcome! My name is \(name)."
    }
}

var store = Store(name: "My Shop", address: "123 Main St.", greeter: Bell())
store.greeter.greet() // => "Ding!"

store.greeter = Person(name: "Itai")
store.greeter.greet() // => "Welcome! My name is Itai."
```

By default, a protocol can be adopted by both value types and object types, i.e., both `struct`s and `class`es. This is a good default because in many cases, there's no reason to restrict who can conform to a protocol.

However, there is one case where this matters. By default, `Store` *owns* its `greeter` property, i.e., when you assign an object to `store.greeter`, it is retained. This is normally fine, except when you have a potentially circular relationship (for example, if `Person` has a reference to the `Store` they work at).

Normally, to break a potential circular chain like this up, you would make the variable `weak`:

```swift
struct Store {
   // ...
   weak var greeter: Greeter?
   //       ^ error: 'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'Greeter'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound
}
```

If you try this, though, you'll get the above error. This is because `weak` only makes sense for objects, not for `struct`s (`struct`s can only be owned because they are value types — every owner just makes a copy of a `struct`, so there is no one central value to retain or release). In this case, to ensure a `weak` reference, you must ensure that `Greeter` an only be an object type.

The way to do this is to constrain the protocol to only allow classes to conform by using `AnyObject` as a constraint:

```swift
protocol Greeter: AnyObject {
    // ...
}
```

Now, `Bell` can't conform to `Greeter` any more (`error: non-class type 'Bell' cannot conform to class protocol 'Greeter'`) but you are allowed to have `weak var greeter: Greeter?` as a variable.

---

So, when should you restrict your protocol to be "class-bound" (using `AnyObject`)? Well, only when you really have to. The one benefit for class-bound protocols is to allow `weak` references to them, and the main use-case for that is with delegate references to prevent circular retains.

For instance, `UITableView` has a `weak` `delegate` property because the `delegate` object is *usually* the view controller which owns the `UITableView` object itself. If the view controller retains the table view, and the table view retains the controller, neither can be released automatically.

So, in the general case, you don't need to worry about the `AnyObject` constraint unless you really do only want classes to conform to the protocol.

Comment: @willy Happy to help! If you get the chance, please consider marking this as the answer using the checkmark button near the upvote/downvote buttons.

Comment: by the way it is here little confused on owned word here "structs can only be owned because they are value types — every owner just makes a copy of a struct, so there is no one central value to retain or release) "
structs can have properties and that doesn`t mean " structs can be owned and owner as well "?
or it is supposed to be owner owned means for cases referencing two object each other and retain cycle just we mentioned this page

Comment: @willy What I meant by this is that `struct`s are values (like `Int` or `String`); every variable which stores a `struct` (like `var bell = Bell()` using the example above) stores a _copy_ of that `struct`, and if it makes changes to the `struct`, those changes are not applied to all of the other copies of the `struct`. This is opposed to objects which are _shared_ by default, so if multiple variables hold references to the same object, one variable making changes to that object will be visible in all of the other variables.

Comment: (There's a little nuance to this because `struct`s can contain objects which are themselves shared, but this is beside the point of the answer and I didn't want to get too off-track.) The main idea is that most `struct`s are _copies_ by default (so when you hold a `struct` you "own" the copy and can freely make changes) vs. objects which are shared (so when you hold a reference to it you might not "own" it or can safely make changes. Does that help a little bit?

Comment: i was thinking before your answers: Being own is same thing having properties. I understood now being own or owned is a topic about the references and objects. I also feel like i am prettey sure about value and reference types.
i searched that nuance actually (some special methods to use class object inside the structs ) and found new things but i need to study on them first carefully :) thanks again